# Menu system with article display and shopping cart

Tags: php, html, css

I have a menu that displays a name depending on where you click on it and allows you to search for a specific category in the database, I also have buttons that are displayed and allow you to add items to the cart, however when I click on the add to cart button the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; makes us stay on this page but an error remains because the variable where the category is stored is forgotten

https://github.com/Sinyaaa/madeinconfigV2

This concerns : Article.php / AffichageArticle.php / navbar.php

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W7Dg.jpg)

[Articles pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM8Rh.jpg)

[Article page regenerate with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHOyC.png)

Comment: We don't debug images

Comment: What's wrong ? There is the github link where you can see the code...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.